# Cant insert e-mail into MySQL table when using HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have following HTML form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>Registreerimine</title>
</head>
<body>
<strong>Registreerimiseks täida järgnevad väljad: </strong><br>
<br>
<form method="POST" action="registreerimine3.php">
<table>
<tr><td>Sinu Tieto e-maili aadress: </td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Eesnimi: </td><td><input type="text" name="eesnimi"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Perekonnanimi: </td><td><input type="text" name="perekonnanimi"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Parool: </td><td><input type="text" name="parool"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Parool uuesti: </td><td><input type="text" name="parooluuesti"></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Registreeri">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and following PHP code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");

if (!$con)

  {

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  }

 mysql_select_db("tieto", $con);


$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$eesnimi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eesnimi']);
$perekonnanimi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['perekonnanimi']);
$parool =  $_POST['parool'];
$parool_uuesti =  $_POST['parooluuesti'];

$salt = rand(1000000,99999999);
$hashed_pwd = sha1('$parool'.$salt);
$sql="INSERT INTO kasutajad6 (email, eesnimi, perekonnanimi, parool, salt ) VALUES ('$email','$eesnimi', '$perekonnanimi', '$parool', '$salt')";

 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

echo "Kasutaja loodud";

 mysql_close($con)

?>
```

When I try to insert data from HTML form into MySQL database, I get following message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp2\htdocs\registreerimine\registreerimine3.php on line 17
```

Everything I need is after that in database except e-mail.
My Database is created with following SQL command:

```
mysql> create table kasutajad6 ( userID int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,email var
char(45) NOT NULL, eesnimi varchar(45) NOT NULL, perekonnanimi varchar(45) NOT N
ULL, parool varchar(45), salt int(8), PRIMARY KEY(userID));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.73 sec)
```

The strange thing is, everything worked fine for a while, but i changed some code and it wont work anymore. Even if i undo changes.

It is a long question and I would be very thankful if someone answers me.

Comment: At begining of PHP code add somethign like this `var_dump($_POST);`. This will show your POST and chack if all fields of this array are present. Your error message say there is no `email` in `$_POST`. You can post result here if you still have problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when the variable is not set. Check if the variable `$email` is set (using isset()) and go through the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index).

I see that you have not named your input tag used to submit the form. Give a name to it `<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Registreeri'>` and put the whole script used for inserting the values inside an `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {}` where submit is the name assigned to the input (submit) tag.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string seems to be the problem here, it "returns the escaped string, or FALSE on error" - see https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string.

If it's returning false, it could be causing an issue for you when inserting into your MySQL database.

It's also deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. Deos it work when you remove the mysql_real_escape_string method from the $_POST['email'] variable?

Comment: Even when I remove mysql_real_escape_string i get the same error.

Comment: The insert into the DB isn't working because that field is NULL, and the email field on your table cannot be null. Something is nulling that field.